# Rails: test a helper that needs access to the Rails environment (e.g. request.fullpath)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have a helper that accesses `request.fullpath`. Within an isolated helper test, `request` is not available. What should I do? Can I somehow mock it or something like that?

I'm using the newest versions of Rails and RSpec. Here's what my helper looks like:

```
def item(*args, &block)
  # some code

  if request.fullpath == 'some-path'
    # do some stuff
  end
end
```

So the problematic code line is #4 where the helper needs access to the `request` object which isn't available in the helper spec.

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Do you have "require 'rspec/rails'" in your spec_helper.rb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can mock the request. I had a whole long answer here describing how to do that, but in fact that's not necessarily what you want.

Just call your helper method on the helper object in your example. Like so:

```
describe "#item" do
  it "does whatever" do
    helper.item.should ...
  end
end
```

That will give you access to a test request object. If you need to specify a specific value for the request path, you can do so like this:

```
before :each do
  helper.request.path = 'some-path'
end
```

---

Actually, for completeness, let me include my original answer, since depending on what you're trying to do it might still be helpful.

Here's how you can mock the request:

```
request = mock('request')
controller.stub(:request).and_return request
```

You can add stub methods to the returned request similarly

```
request.stub(:method).and_return return_value
```

And alternative syntax to mock & stub all in one line:

```
request = mock('request', :method => return_value)
```

Rspec will complain if your mock receives messages that you didn't stub. If there's other stuff Just call your request helper method on the helper object is doing that you don't care about in your test, you can shut rspec up by making the mock a "null object",example. like Like so

```
 request = mock('request').as_null_object
```

It looks like all you probably need to get your specific test passing is this:

```
describe "#item" do
  let(:request){ mock('request', :fullpath => 'some-path') }

  before :each do
    controller.stub(:request).and_return request
  end

  it "does whatever"
end
```

Comment: Ignore my previous answer. It described how to mock the request object, but that's not necessarily the right way to get what you want in a helper spec. See above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like a charm. Still, I'm a bit unsure, why it does. Is the direct call to `helper.my_method` not the same like simple `my_method` call? When testing helpers, should I always call them on the `helper` object? Is there a similar object for controllers and views tests?

Comment: There is! there's a lot of interesting stuff you can do with anonymous controllers; rspec-rails gives you a `controller` object that inherits from ApplicationController, and you can define stub actions on it for testing before_filters or whatever else. Honestly I'm not sure I'm quite expert enough to explain why you need to call your method on the `helper` object. I'd recommend studying the rspec docs at https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-11 if you want to learn more.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to take a look at the docs you mentioned. Wow, There's so much new to Rails since I paused my webdesign activities 3 years ago... But it's great to be part of the big Rails waggon again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In a helper spec, you can access the request using `controller.request` (so `controller.request.stub(:fullpath) { "whatever" }` should work)

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't seem to make the `request` object available in the helper (which is the problem).