# setting request.fullpath in rspec helper test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

The only thing that seems to work is doing something like this

```
let(:request){ stub('request', :fullpath => '/path/to/place?arg=value') }
it 'blah blah' do
...
end
```

The problem for me, is that I want to change this value in the middle of tests, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do that

specifically

```
helper.request.path = '/search?search_type=question'
```

does not work. I get

```
undefined method `fullpath=' for #<ActionController::TestRequest:0x007fe203e47d88>
```

PS: Yes I checked this out [Rails: test a helper that needs access to the Rails environment (e.g. request.fullpath)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528001/rails-test-a-helper-that-needs-access-to-the-rails-environment-e-g-request-fu), nothing except the let instruction seemed to work

Comment: Which type of test is this for? Controller, View, routes, etc?

Comment: I did a quick test and things work for me. Can you post your actual test code that you are trying to use?

Comment: What worked for you exactly?

Comment: The steps in the other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528001. Please post your desired test code so we can better assist you.

Comment: I went and rechecked what I was doing and realized I was calling *method_under_test.should == whatever* instead of *helper.method_under_test.should == whatever*. Doing a *helper.request.fullpath = "something"* didn't work but stubbing and returning to helper.request did. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turns out you have to do ... (using mocha)

```
helper.request.stubs(:fullpath).returns('/search')
```

and call the helper method to test it

```
helper.method.should == true
```